# How Do I change the position of the "new document" on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, document-library

I would like to create a custom menu bar just over the add document to include "add new document" How do I go about this? I'm using out of the box(no designer)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by by adding a URL above `New Document` called `Add New Document` , when you click on it, it will open a new document based on your document Template.by doing the following :

- Edit your Page.
- Add Script Editor

Add the following Code :

```
  <a onclick='CreatDocfromTemplate()' href='#'>Add New Document</a> 

  <script>
    function CreatDocfromTemplate(){
        createNewDocumentWithRedirect2(event,
        'http://epm/Documents/Forms/template.dotx',  
        'http://epm/Documents/','SharePoint.OpenDocuments',
        false,'http://epm/_layouts/CreateNewDocument.aspx?id=http://epm/Documents/Forms/template.dotx',true,0);    
    }        
</script>
```

**Note :**

At the above code

- Replace `http://epm/Documents` with your Doc Library URL
- Replace `http://epm/` with your site URL.

Now You should have a Link called `Add New Document` , when you click on it, it will open a new document based on your document Template.

**[Output]**

[image]

**[Update]**

Regarding **Excel Template** only change `/Forms/template.dotx` to `/Forms/template.xlsx`

```
<a onclick='CreatDocfromTemplate()' href='#'>Add New Document</a> 

  <script>
    function CreatDocfromTemplate(){
        createNewDocumentWithRedirect2(event,
        'http://epm/Documents/Forms/template.xlsx',  
        'http://epm/Documents/','SharePoint.OpenDocuments',
        false,'http://epm/_layouts/CreateNewDocument.aspx?id=http://epm/Documents/Forms/template.xlsx',true,0);    
    }        
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I have an excel file as my template. Does that change anything in the script you posted?

Comment: Here is the code I have; https://codepad.co/snippet/gwv4CXoe

Comment: If you are using a Excel file as your template change /Forms/template.dotx to  /Forms/template.xlsx

Comment: Okay. can you please take a look at my code if any other thing is off?

Comment: @magicrat Is your Document Library called Mitel Form , and your site is https://corporate/teams/bus_evltn/ please confirm to prepare your code based on your entries

Comment: @magicrat Good news Should you set this as answer please if it helped you, it's the true sign beside my answer  , also should you check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to know how to set it as answer. and gain informed badge